# Query to get product options Configurable in order

Tags: orders, export, query

i need the query to get the all configurable options of a product in the order,

In `order`, i wants to `get the configurable product option` like color, size by the `query`

from that i cant used that into the export item.

```
$instance = Mage::getResourceModel("sales/order_grid_collection")->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('total_paid')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('base_currency_code')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_currency_code')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('shipping_name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('billing_name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('updated_at');
$instance->getSelect()
        ->join(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.shipping_description'))
        ->joinLeft(array('sfoi'=>'sales_flat_order_item'),'sfoi.order_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfoi.sku','sfoi.product_type','sfoi.name','sfoi.product_options'))
        ->where('(main_table.status = "processing")')
        ->group(array('sfoi.order_id')); 
$gridcollection = $instance->getFirstItem()->getData();
```

i need product options ie. configurable product - super attribute(color,size)  with this

after selecting 'product_option' i got below,

```
a:10:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:6:{s:4:"uenc";s:80:"aHR0cDovL2lwaG9uZTVjLmVtc21vYmlsZS5jb20vaXBob25lL2lwaG9uZS01cy13aXRoLXBsYW5zLXA,";s:7:"product";s:2:"73";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"EnCATaJe2xLoYzhQ";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:15:"super_attribute";a:3:{i:176;s:2:"12";i:177;s:2:"19";i:180;s:2:"27";}s:3:"qty";i:1;}s:15:"attributes_info";a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:12:"Phone Colour";s:5:"value";s:4:"Gold";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:12:"Phone Memory";s:5:"value";s:5:"64 GB";}i:2;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:12:"Plans";s:5:"value";s:8:"POSTPAID";}}s:11:"simple_name";s:29:"iPhone 5S Gold 64 GB Postpaid";s:10:"simple_sku";s:29:"iPhone 5S Gold 64 GB Postpaid";s:20:"product_calculations";i:1;s:13:"shipment_type";i:0;s:17:"giftcard_lifetime";N;s:22:"giftcard_is_redeemable";i:0;s:23:"giftcard_email_template";N;s:13:"giftcard_type";N;}
```

i need,
Phone Colour - Gold

Plans - POSTPAID

Phone Memory - 64 GB

how to get this

any ideas?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use unserialize() to break the a:10:{...} into an array. Most of what your looking for is probably in there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `$orderItem` all the options are in `$orderItem->getProductOptions()`.

Comment: is it possible to write query instead of code

Comment: this would be `SELECT product_options FROM sales_flat_order_item` but I don't know what you want to do with this.

Comment: i have update the question based on your sugestion, can u help me, to get the values mentioned there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19497459

Comment: is it possible to filter using query?

Comment: I have no idea. This format is not easy to read and I'm not in it.