# How to get all select items options from order object

Tags: magento-1, orders, product-attribute

I am using a custom extension with an `sales_order_save_after` event.
The Method gets an observer objects from which I can get the order instance. 
I am listing then the products using

```
$items=$order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as  $id=>$item){
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
  $selectedAttributes = ???
 ...
}
```

How can I get the list (including names & values) of selected Product attributes?

Comment: you need product's all attributes

Comment: really? Why? I only need selected attributes in the end

Answer (score 1):

it seems that I was looking for the wrong "name" - I don't need the attributes, but the options.
As indicated [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16568/query-to-get-product-options-configurable-in-order) one can obtain the options simply by

```
$options = $item->getProductOptions();
$option_xml = '';
if(is_array($options) && is_array($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])){ 
    foreach ($options['options'] as  $op){ 
        //2Do with $op['option_id'], $op['label'], $op['option_value'], $op['value']
    } 
}
```